# Project.json Settings Based on Solution Configuration

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, xml-documentation, project.json

I have enabled the following `xmlDoc` setting in my `projec.json` file:

```
"buildOptions": {
  "xmlDoc": true
}
```

I only want to comment some of my MVC Controllers to support Swashbuckle and I get lots of warnings complaining that the rest of my code is uncommented. Is there some way of only turning on this setting in `Release` mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true,
    "xmlDoc": true,
    "nowarn": [ "CS1591" ]
},
```

Comment: It would be good if you could give a short sentence explaining why this works (and what exactly that does). Keep in mind that a lot of other people might read that as well.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can enable XML documentation only in Release mode, by adding the following to your project.json:

```
"configurations": {
  "Release": {
    "buildOptions": {
      "xmlDoc": true
    }
  }
},
```

Another option would be be to completely ignore that warning, by adding `"nowarn": ["CS1591"]` to `"buildOptions"`.